# SQL2012 Evaluation expired - Trying to upgrade to fully licensed 2014 version

Tags: sql-server

We have a dev box that one of our developers installed SQL2012 on. The problem is he used an evaluation version. Now I am in the unfortunate situation of it expiring and being unable to access the database.

I tried to upgrade using the 2014 install but it hasn't worked. Because 2012 has expired the SQLSERVER service will not start. Therefore I cannot connect to the database in 2014 and remove 2012.

I tried to un-install 2012 totally but it also took the database with it. Of course, I had taken a snapshot of the VM before trying anything so I restored but am now back at square one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to copy the mdf and ldf files to another location. Then uninstall the 2012 version, install the 2014 version.

Then you just need to drop your mdf and ldf files into the DATA directory and then browse to the Database node in SSMS, right click then select `Attach...` It will pop up a dialog. Point it to your mdf and ldf files and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks, will give this a go when the dev is here to confirm that the databases I've found are the ones he needs. Then I'll give him a telling off!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it has worked a treat. I will be documenting it for my own benefit. And just to add, I made sure that every trace of 2012 and the 2014 upgrade attempt were gone before I created a fresh install of 2014. Just to be sure it would have the best chance of working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any mystery to this - you need a license for 2012 version - certainly you can't upgrade unlicensed software

Comment: You actually can upgrade eval -> your licensed version by using the `/SKUUPGRADE` switch. The Catch is you need to do it before the eval expires as the Engine needs to be running to do the upgrade, and it won't start if it is expired.